# Cannot run sikulix script from command prompt(Windows 10). I can launch the ide and run it though

Tags: sikuli

Sikuli version -2.0.5 I can create a script created from the sikuli IDE and run it using the Run button located at the top.

However I cannot get it to run from a command line? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can understand it better from here
[https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/010-command-line.html][1]

But i would say that you have to write something like this to make it work.

1 - Run CMD in admin

2 - Type something like the following command:

```
java -jar <PATH_TO_SIKULI> -r (run) <PATH_FOR_SIKULI_PROJECT> (ends as .sikuli) -v (verbose in the console) -f (saves log file in path) <WANTED_LOG_FILE_PATH>
```

Example:

```
java -jar C:\Sikuli\Sikulli_2_0_5\sikulixide-2.0.5-win.jar -r C:\Sikuli\tests.sikuli -v -f C:\Sikuli\Sikulli_2_0_5\SikuliLog.txt
```

You can use help like `java -jar <PATH_TO_SIKULI> -h` to understand how you can adjust it for your needs.